# My code passes all of the given tests for CodingBat but doesn't pass "other tests". I'm not sure what my problem is

Tags: java

I'm working on CodingBat for class and can't figure out why my code isn't working. It passes all of the tests that it lists out but then doesn't pass the "other tests". If you could help me figure out what's wrong that would be really helpful. Here is the problem:
Given a string, count the number of words ending in 'y' or 'z' -- so the 'y' in "heavy" and the 'z' in "fez" count, but not the 'y' in "yellow" (not case sensitive). We'll say that a y or z is at the end of a word if there is not an alphabetic letter immediately following it. (Note: Character.isLetter(char) tests if a char is an alphabetic letter.)

Here are the tests that it listed and I passed.

```
countYZ("fez day")    
countYZ("day fez")    
countYZ("day fyyyz")    
countYZ("day yak")    
countYZ("day:yak")    
countYZ("!!day--yaz!!")    
countYZ("yak zak")    
countYZ("DAY abc XYZ")   
countYZ("aaz yyz my")    
countYZ("y2bz")    
countYZ("zxyx")
```

Here is the code I have so far. (I know I could have done it cleaner by converting to lower case but I only realized that afterwards.)

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
  int count = 0;
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  for (int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++) {
    if (!Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) && i>0 && (str.substring(i-1,i).equals("y") || str.substring(i-1,i).equals("z")))
    { count++; }
  }
  if (str.endsWith("y") || str.endsWith("z")) { count++; }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the input where you are failing, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: What are the "other tests" that are failing?

Comment: If I remember correctly from codingbat, "other tests" is a category of tests that aren't disclosed. I would test the edge cases to see if you can find one that doesn't pass

Comment: At least include the passing tests, maybe someone can provide you a failing test in return which will help you work on what you have further.

Comment: well `countYZ(null)` looks like a candidate.

Comment: Have you tried testing an empty string? Right now you are not checking so `str.substring(i-1)` will be an out of bounds exception

Comment: I can't read that long lines -> fail

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:** The way you have set up your logic, your loop looks up until one character before the end of the `String` and then you check the last character with your `if` statement. *However*, your loop only effectively checks the char before `i`, so you are not checking a char. A `String` that this will fail on is:

```
"y z "
```

(Notice the extra space at the end. It can be any other non letter character, which is defined as the ending of the prior word)

This `String` should return 2, but returns 1. The easy fix is to change your loop to:

```
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
```

---

Perhaps a better approach:

Right now you have a mess of boolean conditions to see if the character before is a non alphabetic, if the character at `i` is alphabetic and so on. If I were you I would simply use `toLower()`, and then split on any non alphabetic characters. Then for each `String` in the split array, use the `endsWith` function to easily check if it ends with `z` or `y`. Here's one possible solution:

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
    if(str == null) return 0;
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    int count = 0;
    for(String s : str.split("[^a-z]")) {
        if(s.endsWith("y") || s.endsWith("z")) {
           count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Or java 8+ you can simply do:

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
    if(str == null) return 0;
    return (int)Arrays.stream(str.toLowerCase().split("[^a-z]"))
                      .filter(e -> e.endsWith("y") || e.endsWith("z"))
                      .count();
}
```

Which solves all the test case:
[image]

---

[Link to problem](https://codingbat.com/prob/p199171)

Comment: But it will still technically fail for null strings

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up your code will make it be easier to read and to debug.

[Don't Repeat Yourself!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) Anytime you find yourself writing the same piece of code you are introducing potential bugs due to simple typing errors. Instead, you can move all the checks into a single method, and use `equalsIgnoreCase` to check if a given character matches Y or Z:

```
public static boolean isYOrZ(String s) {
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || s.equalsIgnoreCase("z")) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Right now, your code fails for null strings and for empty strings, so add a check before doing any processing:

```
int count = 0;
if(str == null || str.length() == 0) //check null first or you will get NPE!
    return count;
```

Finally, you can update your code with the new helper method you created. If you understand how regex works, it's easier to use `String.split()` to process your words:

```
public static int countYZ(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    if(str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return count;
    }
    String[] words = str.split("[^A-z]"); //"not an alphabetic letter immediately following it"
    for(String word : words) {
        if(word.length() > 0) { //sanity check
            if(isYOrZ(word.substring(word.length()-1))) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now you can test, write as many weird test cases that you can think of. For example, a huge string of spaces, an empty string, etc. Here are a few I tried:

```
System.out.println(countYZ("heavY yummy TASTY yellow zed buzz"));
System.out.println(countYZ(""));
System.out.println(countYZ(null));
System.out.println(countYZ("fiZz yay"));
System.out.println(countYZ("zzzZZza yyy"));
System.out.println(countYZ("z"));
System.out.println(countYZ("                     "));
System.out.println(countYZ("heavy&testy@!@#BuzZ")); //3
```

Which gives:

```
4
0
0
2
1
1
0
3
```